# How to Only Show Certain Posts in Widget?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am working on a site and I'm having trouble customizing one of the widgets that came with the template. It's a real estate site, and on the main page there is a widget that grabs post's thumbnails and select info. I've broken the widget in two, so one side shows the posts as it normally does and the other side is to show posts that have the field "hot deal" marked as true. See [here](http://titanpanama.com/newsite/)

How can I make it so only `hot deals` shows up on the Specials side? Right now, it's showing in both.
I'm not too versed in PHP, but I usually manage to get through it.

I think this is the php in question

```
<?php 
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
  if ($instance["thumb"]) {
    echo '<figure class="featured-thumbnail thumbnail">';

    if ($instance['thumb_as_link') {
      echo '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '">';
      if ($hotdeal) {
        echo '<div class="hot-deal"></div>';
      }
    }

    if($instance['thumb_w']!=="" || $instance['thumb_h']!==""){
      $thumb_w = $instance['thumb_w'];
      $thumb_h = $instance['thumb_h'];
      echo '<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="<?php echo $thumb_w ?>" height="<?php echo $thumb_h ?>" alt="' . the_title() . '" />';
    } else {
      echo the_post_thumbnail();
    }

    if ($instance['thumb_as_link']) {
      echo '</a>';
    }

    if (is_front_page() ) { 
      if ($area) {
        echo '<div class="area"><?php echo $area; ?></div>';
      }
    }

    echo '</figure>';
  }
}
```

Is there an if statement I could write to achieve the results I'm looking for?

Comment: When it comes to `if, elseif, else` statements in any language, you **need** to indent them properly. Also jumping in an out of php tags like that (i.e. `echo`ing in some spots and writing html in others) makes it even more confusing. Pick one or the other, or look at a php templating engine (like Blade syntax in Laravel).

Comment: @TimLewis I agree with you, but not to be confused with the fact that it will still run.  Simply your code is a bit illegible.  Also, you might want to describe what some of these variables are.

Comment: @James Yes. In simpler terms: "Your code is a mess." I was trying to explain it relatively nicely :P

Comment: Try to make your code more readable. Did you mean this?

Comment: I can read the code but am still unsure what is happening.  I understand that if `$hotdeal` is true you want it to be in a separate column, but I am unsure of what an ideal or sample output should resemble.  Maybe post some examples?  Is it in a separate widget?  Or a separate div for each column?

Comment: Thanks guys. To be honest, this is the code that was in the widget when I bought it. It was originally one widget, but it has now been registered into 2 widgets. Problem is, they both have the same code. Should I post all the code? I just wasn't sure if it was too long to post on here.

Comment: Ok so it seems to me that you want one widget to show the hot deals, and one widget to show none hot deals.  If so, I would say surround both code segments in an if statement. The condition for one should be if hotdeal is true, and the other if it is false.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion of our friend @TimLewis , I tried to solve your problem and I tried also to organize your code to make it more readable.

See:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    if ($instance["thumb"]){
        echo('<figure class="featured-thumbnail thumbnail">');
    }
    if ($instance['thumb_as_link']) {
        echo('<a href="'.the_permalink().'">');
        if ($hotdeal) {
            echo ('class="hot-deal"');
        }
    }
    if($instance['thumb_w']!=="" || $instance['thumb_h']!=="") {
        $thumb_w = $instance['thumb_w'];
        $thumb_h = $instance['thumb_h'];
        echo ('<img src="'. $image." width=".$thumb_w." height=".$thumb_h."     alt=".the_title()."/>");
    } else {
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }
    if ( $instance['thumb_as_link'] ){
        echo ('</a>');
    }
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        if ($area) {
            echo('<div class="area">'.$area.'</div>');
        }
    }
    echo ('</figure>');
}
```

If I didn't make any mistake (what is probable since your code was "a mess"), your error is in this part:

```
 if ($instance['thumb_as_link']) {
    echo('<a href="'.the_permalink().'">');
    if ($hotdeal) {
        echo ('class="hot-deal"');
    }
}
```

Don't use the div, just assign the class hot-deal to your link and then use the CSS make the magic happen on your page.

I hope this helps

Comment: Given a lack of clarity by the question author this is a great answer.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity guys. And thanks for the help. This doesn't seem to do what I want it to. I'm not sure what happened to the original code that I posted...The code in my question above is not what I originally put.

Comment: @taylor_man. Your original post was edited by HurricaneDevelopment. I think that he uses this example code to make your answer more readable. You can edit again and put the two codes for that others can help you.